# Running executable file AFTER "loading" settings from a bat file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm facing some annoying problem which i can't seem to solve and i'll truly appreciate any help.

**The scenario:**

i want to run an executable file and to pass arguments to him , in order for the executable file to run there is a need to first run an batch file that set high amount of settings (other wise crushes).

for simplicity the wished out-come that also working is :

`"c:/.../../setting_file.bat && c:/../../exe_file.exe args"`

What i tried to do is to use the **Runtime.exec** and passing it the exact variables as i mentioned above.

yet it seems like it doesn't save the process of the batch file so the program crushes (i guess it misses all the env variables that file was setting).

**The question :**

How do i run a bat file that will set some setting and after it finished run an executable file that is familiar with what so ever that bat file did.

Thanks in advanced, Gal.

Comment: would be helpful to see (a relevant part of) your `setting_file.bat`

Comment: I'll extract the non relevant part of it and post it here as soon as i can , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the batch script to continue, use `CALL` to invoke the batch script.

See `CALL /?`.

Comment: I'm going over this right now to check it out , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i solved it eventually , finally you **can** run a batch file and then exe file with if you are using the "&&" operator , just need to format the string correctly and to use the correct overloaded method of Runtime.exec.

Thanks for the quick answer which lead me into solving this , highly appreciated!
Take care